# an inequality for a positive random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

let be X positive random variable, $q \geqslant1$ . show that

$\sum\limits_{k \geqslant 0} {q{k^{q - 1}}P\left( {X \geqslant k + 1} \right) \leqslant E({X^q})}$.

this is what i did :

since we can write ${X^q} = \int_0^X {q{t^{q - 1}}dt} $, we have :

$E({X^q}) = \int_0^\infty  {q{t^{q - 1}}P(X \geqslant t)dt}$

how can i continue?

Comment: By noticing that $qt^{q-1}P(X\geqslant t)\geqslant qk^{q-1}P(X\geqslant k+1)$ for every $t$ in $(k,k+1)$, for every $k\geqslant0$.

Comment: ok, i understand now. thanks